# Add a new field to all documents of a collection with the value from the document field into MongoDB (Mongoose) with records of 300K+

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I'm having difficulty with adding another field to all records of the `user`'s collection with a value from each document. I'm familiar with using `$set` with `db.model.updateMany`, and `$addFields` with aggregation pipeline, I've used both to solve problems in the past, in this case, I have to perform some logics/calculation before adding the value, right here is where my problem lies.

Say, I have the schema like this:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "wallets": {...},
      "avatar": "",
      "isVerified": false,
      "suspended": false,
      "country": "Nigeria",
      "_id": "123",
      "resetPasswordToken": "",
      "email": "example@gmail.com",
      "phone": "08012398743",
      "name": "Agbakwuru Nnaemeka Kennedy ",
      "role": "user",
    },
    {...}
}
```

I want to add a new field `phoneNumber`, that will take the value of the existing field `phone`, but before adding, I'd like to run a logic on it, as some of the phone values are having whitespaces most of them are not correctly formatted, and I'd like to prepend the country code to the `phone` value, before adding it to the new `phoneNumber` field.

I was able to get this done using a cursor from Mongoose `db.mode.aggregate` method, with `$match` filter, and adding the field to each document with the aggregate `$addFields` pipeline, this prove to take a whole lot of time, I had to stop the operation as it's taking too much time to run.

I'd like to believe there's a better way out there, please, I will appreciate any help.

Edit:

Here's the aggregation I'm using:

```
const userCursor = User.aggregate([{$match: {phone: {$exists: true}}}]);
for await (const doc of userCursor) {
  await User.findByIdAndUpdate(doc._id, {$set: {
          phoneNumber: convertPhoneNumber({phoneNumber: doc.phone.replace(/\s+/g, "")})}
  });
}
```

The `convertPhoneNumber` is a helper method I defined in my utils to prepend the country dealing code to the phone number.

Comment: Can you share us the aggregation you are using? We need to identify where the bottleneck is to better help you out.

Comment: @ray I have edited my question to include the aggregation I'm using, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [@Jeremy Thille](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021703/jeremy-thille)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69674606/8018867) I was able to solve it with MongoDB Compass `mongo` command line with the below snippet.

```
db.users.find({phone: {$exists: true}}).forEach( user => {
  const phone = user.phone.replace(/\s+/g, "");
  const phoneNumber = `+234${phone.slice((phone.length - 10))}`;
  db.users.updateOne({_id: user._id}, {$set: {phoneNumber}});
})
```

Downside was it took like 10-15 minutes to update 300K documents, this was an outstanding improvement as against my initial implementation that took over a day just to update a few tens of thousands documents.

Answer (score 1):

I would attempt to run a script like that directly in the `mongo` command line, or Robo3T :

```
db.getCollection("users").find({}).forEach( doc => {

    doc.users.forEach( user => {

        // do your logic here
        let phoneNumber = "12345";
        phoneNumber = "+007" + phoneNumber;

        user.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    })

    db.users.save(doc);
})
```

It will still take a while on 300k+ documents, but give it a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy, I will try the snippet, I would like to ask, do you by any chance have the knowledge that this same logic can run on MongoDB Compass?

Comment: Your answer helped me with the solution Jeremy :)

Comment: Ha, you're welcome. Unfortunately I have never used Compass, I use Robo3T as a GUI

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$function`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) and call that javascript code in the database.

This requires >=MongoDB 4.4

```js
db.Users.update(
  {phone: {$exists: true}},
  [{$set: {phoneNumber:
            {
             "$function": {
             "body": YOUR_convertPhoneNumber_FUNCTION_DEF,
             "args": ["$phoneNumber"],
             "lang": "js"
             }
            }])
```

Also if the code of convertPhoneNumber, can be written in MongodBD using aggregate operators you can avoid the javascript also.

The above is a pipeline update and we can use all aggregate operators when updating.

---

**Edit**

If mongoose has problem with the `$function` or nodejs driver method has problem with pipeline update you can also do.

```js
db.runCommand(
   {
      update: "yourCollectionName",
      updates: [
         {
           q: {phone: {$exists: true}},
           u: 
           [{$set: {phoneNumber:
            {
             "$function": {
             "body": YOUR_convertPhoneNumber_FUNCTION_DEF,
             "args": ["$phoneNumber"],
             "lang": "js"
             }
            }],
           multi: true
         }
      ],
      ordered: false
   }
)
```

Comment: Hi @Takis_, I tried using the `$function` aggregation pipeline, but I got this error: ```Cannot run server-side javascript without the javascript engine enabled```, I read about it, I'm required to contact MongoDB team to enable it, but I use a managed DB with DigitalOcean, with DO, server-side scripting is disabled by default.

Comment: if you are doing pipeline update, you can use all the aggregate operators, and you probably dont need javascript, i guess convertPhoneNumber can be done with aggregate operators.

Comment: I have this snippet:

`await User.aggregate([
        {
          $addFields:
            {
              phoneNumber:
                {
                  $function:
                    {
                      body: function (phone) {
                        return convertPhoneNumber({phoneNumber: phone})
                      },
                      args: ["$phone"],
                      lang: "js"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      ]);`

I got this error as soon as I run it:  `MongoServerError: Cannot run server-side javascript`

Comment: no you cant do this, you need to include the body of the `convertPhoneNumber` in the definition. even if javascript was allowed it would not work, mongodb cant see to run your function, all this code will run in the database

Comment: Thanks, I got the error I need to include the body function: `The body function must be specified`, I will include the `convertPhoneNumber` logic inside of the body function too and see if this solve it

Comment: I believe the `$function` aggregation can only run on native MongoDB driver not on Mongoose ORM, seems this is the reason for the error: `MongoServerError: Cannot run server-side javascript without the javascript engine enabled`

Comment: i updated the answer, you are doing update i dont think you need mongoose, also if nodejs updateMany doesn't support pipeline updates, you can run it as command.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I ran the command against a mongo shell (MongoDB Compass shell), and I was met with the same error, I guess I will try it with RoboMongo, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Bulk Operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/), this updates the collection in batches of 1000 documents:

```
var bulkOperations = [];
db.getCollection("users").find({}).forEach(doc => {
   doc.users.forEach(user => {
      user.phoneNumber = convertPhoneNumber({phoneNumber: user.phone.replace(/\s+/g, "")});
   })
   bulkOperations.push({
      updateOne: {
         filter: { id: doc._id },
         update: { $set: { users: doc.users } }
      }
   });
   if (bulkOperations.length > 1000) {
      db.getCollection("users").bulkWrite(bulkOperations, { ordered: false });
      bulkOperations = [];
   }
})
if (bulkOperations.length > 0) 
   db.getCollection("users").bulkWrite(bulkOperations, { ordered: false });
```

Comment: thanks, I read about Bulk, but did not do much about it, mostly because I'm not sure how it works, I will give this a try now.